# What is the right way to do this ( On Click Recyclerview row i wants to add that row to last position in recyclerview )?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am finding the right way to do this!
On Click Recyclerview row i wants to add that row to last position in recyclerview and again click on the same row that row will move to previous position in recyclerview

What i am doing to solve this-
 I am using 2 recycler view to show clicked(checked) and non clicked (unchecked) item separately

Is this a Right way to do this?

So suggest me, What is the  Right way to do that?

Comment: can you add some code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the logic in the List (Order the items) and after that call notifyDataSetChanged() in order to refresh the list.